# Mysql task: DELETE+INSERT or SELECT+UPDATE

Tags: mysql

MySQL database has only one table `products`. Table record contains 1 integer autoincrement primarykey, 1 integer `modified_time` field and 10 varchar fields.

Two times a day CRON launches process that receives 700.000 XML records with new/updated/old products from other server. Usually there are about 100.000 updated on new products a day (other 600.000 dont change).

The question is what way will be faster 
1) Make something like `DROP TABLE` then recreate same table or `DELETE * FROM products`. Then `INSERT` everything we receive (700k records).
2) Start loop on every XML record, compare `modified_time` field and UPDATE if XML `modified_time` is newer than `modified_time` from database.

As I understand second way will lead to 700k SELECT queries, 100k UPDATE queries and some DELETE queries.

So what way will be faster? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to know which is faster, try both and see which works better on your data and on your system.  I would expect the first method to work better, because multiple updates can be slow.

Comment: That will depend on how many rows change. I would just benchmark it, anyway, i guess `insert ... on duplicate key update` migth be agood choice